# Can I manually configure a domain name for Windows Home Server 2011 Remote Access?

Tags: remote-access, domain-name, windows-home-server

Windows Home Server 2011 supports remote web access. The wizard conveniently configured my router (apparently) and then asks to configure a domain name. I have a domain name currently parked with a local registrar, but it is not one of the 'supported' registrars.

WHS setup informs me that I can either get a new domain name through their wizard, or transfer my domain to a supported registrar and then they can configure it for me. Does anyone know if it is possible to manually configure the domain name to point to my home server through without transferring to a Microsoft-approved registrar?

I guess I'm curious as to whether Microsoft simply manages name-server references for the domain name and can only do that with some agreed partners, or whether they do something more complicated for routing traffic to the home server (perhaps some sort of VPN? I potentially don't know what I'm talking about here).

Comment: One thing that Micrsoft will be doing through their partner registries is managing dynamic IP problems. Presuming that you're on a consumer internet connection, it is quite likely that your router's external IP changes periodically. WHS has an agent installed on the server that can talk to back to Microsoft and let them know when your IP changes, and then they change the DNS record to point to your new IP automatically. If you set up your DNS record yourself you're also going to have manage any changes in your router's IP yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the info. My ISP provides static IP addresses so that won't be an issue (at least not at this stage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You bought the domain already. You need a DNS host to point the domain at. At the DNS Host you'll need to configure a record, like `myserver.example.com`, to point to your IP. You already have your router configured to forward the IP to your server.

In Professional Administration we usually do all this stuff manually, no "convenient" wizard to do it for us.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the record so will see if it works in the next day or so :)

Answer (score 1):

My thought would be, specifically because they're talking about registrars, that they are just managing domain names.  From the research I've done it looks like they might also offer a signed certificate, which really isn't that big of a deal for most home use.  If you have control of a domain and a static IP, simply point it to the server and you should be good to go.